# Saturation mode of BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt

What happens when Vce=0V and when Vce=-1V?
In the Ic-Vcb characteristic graph, most of them shows around Vcb=-0.4V.
So if Vce=0V(i.e. Vcb=-0.7V) and Vce=-1V(i.e. Vcb=-1.7V) what happens?

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. It is not possible to understand exatly what voltages and terminals and situation you are referring to. For example, your 1st sentence reads: "What happens when Vce=0V and when Vce=-1V? " EITHER that's a type, or you have two situations in mind AND you do not ask wjat happens to xxx, just "what happens. IF you mean Vbe say so. If you mean "what is the Vce saturation voltage, say so. You also do not specify device or chemistry. Is this silicon npn, or germanium pnp, or ...?

Comment: Note that text will wrap around if you do not add 2 spaces at end of lines. If you want to start a new line add 2 spaces at the line end.

Answer (score 1):

Alert for major assumption- you should pay attention to Russell and fix your question- assuming you are talking about an **NPN silicon BJT**, when the collector voltage becomes much more negative than the base, substantial current will flow across the forward-biased base-collector junction.

If there is -1.7V across the C-B junction the transistor will probably be destroyed, and maybe even with -1V.